# How we can update choice field in Django forms without reloading the server?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Here is my forms.py

```
class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
    email=forms.EmailField(label="Email",max_length=50,widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your email',"class":"form-control"}))
    password=forms.CharField(label="Password",min_length=8,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your password',"class":"form-control"}))
    name=forms.CharField(label="Name",min_length=4,max_length=20,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your name',"class":"form-control"}))
    username=forms.CharField(label="Username",min_length=4,max_length=10,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter a unique username',"class":"form-control"}))
    gender_choice=(
        ("Male","Male"),
        ("Female","Female")
    )
    manegers=Manager.objects.all()
    maneger_list=[]
    for maneger in manegers:
        small_maneger=(maneger.id,maneger.name)
        maneger_list.append(small_maneger)

    staffs=Staff.objects.all()
    staff_list=[]
    for staff in staffs:
        small_staff=(staff.id,staff.name)
        staff_list.append(small_staff)

    manager_idd=forms.ChoiceField(label="Manager",choices=maneger_list,widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
    staff_id=forms.ChoiceField(label="Staff",choices=staff_list,widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
    cnic=forms.CharField(label="Cnic",max_length=13,min_length=13,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',"class":"form-control"}))
    gender=forms.ChoiceField(label="Gender",choices=gender_choice,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'placeholder':'Select',"class":"form-control"}))
    contact_number=forms.CharField(label="Contact#",max_length=10,min_length=10,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'+92xxxxxxxxxx (enter 10 digits)',"class":"form-control"}))
```

I have to reload server again and again when I put data otherwise choice field does not show update name. I want to remove this thing. Is thing problem will be continued when I deploy my website to host.

Comment: Use a `ModelChoiceField` and pass a queryset.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset

Comment: I am getting output like this. How can i remove name written and these brackets?

Comment: don't use `.values(..)`. Just `queryset=Staff.objects.all()` for example.

Comment: please edit the question with the related model(s) and the current state of the form.

Comment: I am getting an issue, as i used modelfieldchoice, it is working fine but in forms where it displays name,in database it is also delivering name in field of foreign key id. Previously, i was saving the id in database but showing the name in pop down menu but reloading server error was coming but now i replaced it with modelchoice field it shows me name and in database, it is also saving name but i want key to save. how can i do that?